# Irrational Integral

Tags: real-analysis, integration, indefinite-integrals

I've tried in many ways to compute this integral but I'm not able to find any solution. Even Wolfram can not compute this. So my question is: Is that even possible to compute?
$$\int { \frac { dx }{ 1+\sqrt { x } +\sqrt { x+1 } +\sqrt { x+2 }  }  }$$

Comment: Maple can compute this integral!

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner Is the answer short enough to post?

Comment: @saulspatz. Just as you, I would like to see the answer. With two among the three $\sqrt {..}$, the answer is "quite simple". With all three ... ?

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner Please post the answer that Maple give. I try to solve this integral and I think that the best substitution are $\sqrt { x } =sinh\alpha$ and $\sqrt { x } =tan\theta$

Comment: I think the answer is too large for the table here

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner is there  a way to share the result?

Comment: Yes. there is a way, tomorrow i will post it.

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner Thank you so much

Comment: Why?  Why are you interested in this integral?  If we knew why you were interested in the antiderivative of this function, it might help us provide better answers.  For example, do you really need an explicit formula, or do you only need numerical approximations for certain limits of integration?  Where did this integrand come from?  Is this an exercise of some sort?

Comment: Mathematica **12.0** can compute this integral. Answer is to large  for the table here.

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

Let $x=u-1$ ,

Then $\int\dfrac{dx}{1+\sqrt x+\sqrt{x+1}+\sqrt{x+2}}$

$=\int\dfrac{du}{1+\sqrt u+\sqrt{u-1}+\sqrt{u+1}}$

$=\int\dfrac{\sqrt{u-1}+\sqrt{u+1}-1-\sqrt u}{(1+\sqrt u+\sqrt{u-1}+\sqrt{u+1})(\sqrt{u-1}+\sqrt{u+1}-1-\sqrt u)}~du$

$=\int\dfrac{\sqrt{u-1}+\sqrt{u+1}-1-\sqrt u}{(\sqrt{u-1}+\sqrt{u+1})^2-(1+\sqrt u)^2}~du$

$=\int\dfrac{\sqrt{u-1}+\sqrt{u+1}-1-\sqrt u}{u-1-2\sqrt u+2\sqrt{u^2-1}}~du$